# no longer able to start my azure function in vscode

Tags: azure-functions

I'm in windowns 10.  I was developing my python azure function in vscode and test it in local host. Everything was fine until recently. I tried to start my azure functions, but I got error messages like below:

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'grpc_tools'
  File "c:\users\myusername\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\python\3.7\windows\x64\grpc\__init__.py", line 2034, in <module>
    import grpc_tools
  File "c:\users\myusername\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\python\3.7\windows\x64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    import grpc
  File "c:\users\myusername\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\python\3.7\windows\x64\azure_functions_worker\main.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import dispatcher
  File "c:\users\myusername\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\python\3.7\windows\x64\worker.py", line 59, in <module>
    from azure_functions_worker import main
```

I have not changed anything since last time I tested my azure function.  Have no idea why I got the error messsage.  Does anyone know what the error message mean? what cold be the solution to the issue?

Something wrong with the `azure-functions-core-tools`?  The problem is I have not changed anything at all. But now it stopped working for no reason.  Really appreciate it if anyone can help. Thanks.

Comment: Does your app in a subfolder and using Core Tools 2.x as well? If so, go to the root folder of your app and run `func start` again. Also you could try to update function core tools to the latest version.

Comment: Any update on this question?:)

Answer (score 2):

Running `func start` from the cli works for me; running from VS Code still produces errors.

Also, trying to manually install the packages works; however, I consider this a workaround. Also you will be going down the rabbit hole, as every time you add a package, some other one will not work.

Comment: should I do `pip install grpc_tools`?  It failed and asked me to install `grpcio_tools`.  I did that and it says I miss other modules.  Should I keep installing? Do you mean that works for you?   should I install  inside venv or outside?   super thanks!

Comment: Well installing them manualy will just give other import errors. When you isntall all the grpcio things needed, it will then crash on:
 "cannot import name 'enable_deterministic_proto_serialization' from 'google.protobuf'"

You can just run the fuction from the comand line, func host start or func start works for me (without installing anything extra)

But this means you do not have a debugger attached and you cannot debug the application, but you are able to run it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue start popping up yesterday after a few months of not working with Azure Functions and on a new laptop.

I found that you can disable the exception alerts in the Visual Studio Code debugger.

[image: Which can be found in the bottom left corner while debugging under breakpoints]

By default, *Uncaught Exceptions* and *User Uncaught Exceptions* are checked: uncheck them and that will prevent the debugger from showing exceptions.